# What does it mean for two conjectures to be incompatible?

Tags: definition

What does it mean for two conjectures to be incompatible?

I read about Incompatibility of two Hardy-Littlewood Conjectures.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hardy-LittlewoodConjectures.html

What does it mean?

Comment: My guess would be that they cannot both be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that once you prove either of the conjectures to be true, you've automatically proven the other one to be false.

Comment: Can they both be false?

Comment: @ppthegreat: Yes, they can